# Floating Button Show NullPointer Exception on OnClick Function

Tags: android

```
public class MaterialUpConceptFakePage extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRootView;
    private ViewPager vpCustomerTestimonials;
    private CirclePageIndicator cpiBanner;
    private CustomerTestimonialsPagerAdapter customerTestimonialsPagerAdapter;
    FloatingActionButton FAB;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);

        mRootView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        vpCustomerTestimonials = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vpCustomerTestimonials);
        cpiBanner = (CirclePageIndicator) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cpiBanner);

        FAB = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        initRecyclerView();
        initslideViewpager();
        FAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), FAQAndTermsOfUse.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

This is my Code when i apply On Click function then it throw null Pointer Exception On Floating Button Click when app Launch when i remove onClick function then its work fine please tell me what i am doing wrong why it show Exception

Comment: show your xml file

Comment: Did you see your xml, i mean to say does it contain fab id (is it correct ?)

One more thing check FAB in your activity or in your Fragment.

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/G3WzANwpYTUaDTkQnzEaJN

Comment: its in Fraemnet

Comment: @DäñishShärmà any Solution ?

Comment: add stacktrace and add your layout-file.

Comment: @ResearchDevelopment check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Check your FAQAndTermsOfUse.class

Note: It should be extenting AppCompatActivity

for e.g.:

```
public class FAQAndTermsOfUse extends AppCompatActivity
{

{
```

and check your manifest, have you declared this activity in manifest.

```
<activity
            android:name=".FAQAndTermsOfUse "
            android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

Comment: i have changed that also

Comment: then just clean build. it should work now, Edit your question with your manifest and FAQAndTermsOfUse  class

Comment: still same exception why this issue cumming  cant we add Floting Button in Fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Fragment allow to add FloatingActionButton. I think your problem may be in FAQAndTermsOfUse.class, please verify FAQAndTermsOfUse is added within manifest file?

Comment: yes its added already i am also shock why this issue is coming

Answer (score -2):

Check your xml file and make sure it contains FAB with id 'R.id.fab'.

Comment: <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/user_avatar"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="8dp" /> check this is my xml

Comment: any solution for this